# Check whether whole sheet is selected or not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, vsto, vba

How to check whether user has selected whole excel worksheet or not?.
I have tried to use following.

```
selection.cells.count
```

but it gives a out of present range exception.

is there any way to do the same?

Comment: 2) and do you mean the entire sheet, or the entire used oportion of the sheet?

Comment: `.CountLarge` can be used for Excel 2007+

Comment: Good point raise by Tim Williams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to plagiarize brettdj's code and create a version to test if the entire sheet is selected.  While I'm intrigued by his use of a string to contain TRUE, FALSE and failure values, I'd just go with a Boolean, so people like me won't have to think too hard.

```
Sub CheckSelection()
Dim IsMatch As Boolean
Dim ErrNum As Long

With ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    IsMatch = (.Range(.Cells(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Address = Selection.Address)
    ErrNum = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ErrNum <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "test failed: have you selected part of the sheet", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox IsMatch = True
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to test whether the `UsedRange` was indentical to the `Selection` in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) then

1. You need to ensure the `UsedRange` has been updated
2. Catering for errors if there is no range selection is also needed

something like ths gives either

- a warning message for an error (no selection)
- True for the same `Address` strings
- False for different `Address` strings

**code**

```
Sub TestData()
Dim strTest As String
'force usedrange to update
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
On Error Resume Next
strTest = (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address = Selection.Address)
On Error GoTo 0
If Len(strTest) = 0 Then
MsgBox "test failed: have you selected part of the sheet", vbCritical
Else
MsgBox strTest
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Although the idea that someone has selected *exactly* the `UsedRange` seems strange to me. Possibly crossed wires:)

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @TimWilliams in the comments, if you select the whole worksheet, the count will overflow an int (i.e. the `Count` property) causing the "out of present range" exception.  To get around this use the `CountLarge` property.  In C#, the `CountLarge` property is an object.  To use it, cast it to a long.

```
long cellCount = (long)selectedRange.Cells.CountLarge;
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old discussion, but I came here from a Google search. For anyone else who finds this, an easier way would probably be just to use ".address". For example

```
If Selection.address = Cells.address then Msgbox "You selected an entire sheet!"
```